# HASHMAP utilization for dynamic Pivot Table

Tags: hashmap

I would like create a dynamic Pivot table in Java and I have code snippet in PERL. I would like to use the same process to create this dynamic pivot table in Excel.

I a dealing with Json response and I have limited knowledge in Java hence need help on Code perspective.

I have tried to use the HASHMAP to imitate

++$pivot{$app}{$device}{$browser}; but I am not able to do the same.

I need to produce the same like below in Java.

```
APP 1   AAP 2   APP3    App4
```

Device 1    7   92  53  9
Browser 1   7   54  39  7
Browser 2       10  4
Browser 3       1       1
Device 2        1
Browser 1
Browser 2
Browser 3
Device 3        1
Browser 1
Browser 2
Browser 3
Grand Total

```
    $app = $responseapps5[$k];
    $device = $responseclientdevice[$k];
    $browser = $responseclientbrowser[$k];
    $userid = $responseid[$k];

    ++$pivot{$app}{$device}{$browser};
      ++$pivot{$app}{'TOTAL'}{$browser};
      ++$pivot{$app}{'TOTAL'}{'TOTAL'};
      ++$pivot{$app}{$device}{'TOTAL'};
      ++$pivot{'TOTAL'}{$device}{$browser};
    #++$pivot{$app}{$browser};
       ++$categ{'device'}{$device};
       ++$categ{'browser'}{$browser}; 
       ++$app{$app};

$row1++;
#print Dumper $app;
```